# How can I show specific locations within a specified radius on Bing maps using V8 Web Control?

Tags: php, maps, bing

at the moment I'm working on a software which should be able to show specific locations within a specified radius from a location using Bing Maps. The problem is that I can't find any solution to do this. This topic isn't addressed in the official V8 Web Control documentation and it seems like there's nobody who asked this question before, at least I can't find it. The application is written in PHP.

I'd be very happy if someone would know a solution for this problem. Please don't tell me to use Google Maps or something else instead, I'm not allowed to.

Thank you!

Comment: What are these specific locations?  Do you have the co-ordinates or do you need Bing to work these out for you?

Comment: I get the coordinates from Bing but I think I already found the solution, it's called nearby results and it's in the documnetation!